# How can I sum up values over time and deduct them as soon as they are not needed anymore?

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2

Hi and apologies if this was asked already, I could not find anything since an hour so I'll ask:

I have data in this style (sorry for the horrible formatting, how can I make these prettier?):

```
person start_time end_time amount
A   2019-10-04  2020-04-21  10
A   2019-12-10  2020-01-09  20
B   2019-11-04  2020-08-21  30
B   2019-12-10  2020-01-20  15
C   2019-12-20  2020-03-19  5
```

So, I want to be able to plot the sum of the `amount` per person with ggplot2 over time until today (or sys_date).

This means, for person `A`, the plot should show 10 from 2019-10-04 until 2019-12-10, and afterwards it should jump to 30 (10+20). This is until 2020-01-09 (since this is in the past), where the amount should go back to 10.

Similarly, for person B the amount should be 30 between 2019-11-04 and 2019-12-10, afterwards it should be 45, and fall back to 30 on 2020-01-20.

I tried something along:

```
SumAmount <- data %>%
    group_by(person,start_time,end_time) %>%
    summarise(cumulatedAmount = sum(amount))
```

But this isn't what I need...

Thanks a lot and apologies again for the poor formatting.

Comment: Try grouping by person, arranging by date and then mutate with cumsum() (i.e. data %>% group_by(person) %>% arrange(end_time) %>% mutate(cumulatedAmount = cumsum(amount))

Comment: Thanks John! Looks a lot better, but in the ggplot output the amount only goes up, but not down. As soon as the end_time is reached, the cumulatedAmount should be reduced by that amount. Do you have an idea for that too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one idea. We can calculate the total amount of each date and then plot the total amount.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  # Convert to date class
  mutate_at(vars(ends_with("time")), ymd) %>%
  # Create a date sequence and expand it
  mutate(Date = map2(start_time, end_time, seq.Date, by = 1)) %>%
  unnest(cols = Date) %>%
  # Calculate the total amount for each date
  group_by(person, Date) %>%
  summarize(amount = sum(amount))

ggplot(dat2, aes(x = Date, y = amount, color = person)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Here is another option. This is the same way to expand the data frame based on date. After that, we can use `stat_summary` to plot the data.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  # Convert to date class
  mutate_at(vars(ends_with("time")), ymd) %>%
  # Create a date sequence and expand it
  mutate(Date = map2(start_time, end_time, seq.Date, by = 1)) %>%
  unnest(cols = Date) 

ggplot(dat2, aes(x = Date, y = amount, color = person)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y = sum, geom = "path")
```

[image]

**Update**

This solution add 0 to the next date of the last date for each person

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  # Convert to date class
  mutate_at(vars(ends_with("time")), ymd) %>%
  # Create a date sequence and expand it
  mutate(Date = map2(start_time, end_time, seq.Date, by = 1)) %>%
  unnest(cols = Date) %>%
  # Calculate the total amount for each date
  group_by(person, Date) %>%
  summarize(amount = sum(amount))

dat3 <- dat2 %>%
  # Find the last date for each person
  filter(Date == max(Date)) %>%
  # Add one day to the last date for each person
  # Set amount to be 0
  mutate(Date = Date + 1, amount = 0)

# Combine data frames
dat4 <- bind_rows(dat2, dat3)

ggplot(dat4, aes(x = Date, y = amount, color = person)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "person start_time end_time amount
A   '2019-10-04'  '2020-04-21'  10
A   '2019-12-10'  '2020-01-09'  20
B   '2019-11-04'  '2020-08-21'  30
B   '2019-12-10'  '2020-01-20'  15
C   '2019-12-20'  '2020-03-19'  5",
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: That works very nicely, thank you! I'd like the lines go to 0 as soon as the very last end_date per person is reached. How can I implement this in the code?